# How to call function from another function in VBA? (Error in results)

Tags: arrays, vba, error-handling, range

I am working on 2 functions in VBA.

Function 1:

```
Function sort_range(data_o As Range)

Set wf = WorksheetFunction
N = data_o.Rows.Count
data_sort1 = data_o
data_sort2 = data_o

For i = 1 To N
    data_sort1(i, 1) = wf.Min(data_sort2)
    data_sort2(wf.Match(data_sort1(i, 1), data_sort2, 0), 1) = 999999
Next i

sort_range = data_sort1

End Function
```

Function 2:

```
Function sort_range_2(data_o1 As Range, k_default As Long)

Set wf = WorksheetFunction

data_sort3 = sort_range(data_o1)
sort_range_2 = data_sort3(k_default, 1)

End Function
```

When I input "999,999,999,999,999" into "data_o" of sort_range, sort_range_2 returns 999 (which is correct).

However, sort_range_2 returns an error if I input e.g. "999,1.457,999,999,0.157" into "data_o".

Could anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. The first and already a tricky one. Could you explain what the functions are doing and how you are using them?

Comment: What `k_default` does mean? What does `sort_range_2` return? I mean, what type... Your code does not show the return type. It looks to be an element of the sorted array, but we do not see your data you processed. And, how do you input "999,999,999,999,999" into "data_o", since it is a range?